# Why did Britain place naval mines in their own Channel in WW2?

Tags: world-war-two, war, naval, britain

Reading about [Naval Mines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naval_mine), I came across a curious claim:

> for example, during World War II, Britain declared simply that it had mined the English Channel, North Sea, and French coast.

It's not cited, but there's a similar claim down a ways saying that Britain did the same thing during the first world war.

So the questions begin. **Why did Britain mine their own channel during WW2?**

Britain's navy was vastly superior to the Kriegsmarine, or so I've been told, so I don't see why they would want to cut off timely naval access between their east and west shores.

Could it actually be the case that Britain mined only the **southern** part of the Channel? Or maybe they used deep mines only triggerable by submarines?

Comment: When one puts mines there are usually passages which allow moving through them given a mine field map.

Comment: Additionally, British ships going through the channel would be too close to German shore artillery and airfields; I think that unless strictly necessary any sane captain would cross through the North Sea

Comment: I think they placed minefields primarily against German submarines, which were so hindered to operate in British coastal waters where there was no protection of ships through convoys (single ship traffic).

Comment: @SJuan76 the North Sea is actually east of Britain. Did you mean the ships would go around the north coast of Britain to get from east to west?

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant

Answer (score 8):

The initial British/French mining in the channel was as an anti-submarine barrage. Later anti-invasion fields were laid.

Later in the war offensive fields were laid on the other side of the channel.

Details of RN mine laying in WW2 may be found [here](http://www.naval-history.net/xGM-Ops-Minelaying.htm#1)

Answer (score 3):

In order for the Allies, specifically in this case England, to create a naval blockade against the Axis--Germany in the north--it was practical for England to cover as much area as possible without physically being present with warships.

During WWII Germany had solidified it's reach to the Netherlands, Poland, northern France, Belgium, Denmark, and Norway. All of these areas were potential ports for both German imports and exports. With that, it is necessary to cut off any potential traffic through that gigantic area of sea.

Of course, as it was implied above, England had its own interest to protect her own ports and ships against German submarines who were incredibly skilled and populous especially in the Atlantic seaboard and the areas identified above.

Nonetheless, this question is more complex than the answer above. There are many details involved. Rather, I have given a general answer.

Comment: England is not the country in question, the name of the country is the United Kingdom (of Great Britain and Northern Ireland) often abbreviated to the UK (or just Britain) and its navy is known as The Royal Navy, abbreviated to RN. Also your answer is unsourced (and superficial). The Channel was mined before the fall of France.

Comment: Conrad, please do not bore me with technicalities. I am well aware of what the the Royal Navy is, and England is an accepted extension of the usage of the U.K. in academia. Nonetheless, I cannot seem to find a bibliography for the aforementioned post that you have suggested about mined areas. If you can, please specify where navlhistory.net received their sources. I have a degree in European history-- more specifically, the Second Industrial Revolution, Weimar Republic, and until the end of World War II.

Comment: oswana21: Try reading what the Naval History Net says about its sources: _Further details are available in the Naval Staff History (Mining) copies of which are held in the National Archives at Kew and in the Naval Historical Branch, HM Dockyard Portsmouth. Reference can also be made to the individual Chronologies of War Service for the warships listed in this Digest. These contain the identity and dates of the individual Operations concerned._

Comment: _I have a degree in European history-- more specifically, the Second Industrial Revolution, Weimar Republic, and until the end of World War II._ Irrelevant qualification waving, I'm afraid on this matter I will judge you by the quality of your post.

Comment: So, you are arguing that mines were not set in the water as part of a naval blockade? I gave an extremely broad answer; I made that quite clear. I think you are splitting hairs here. Can you be more specific about my error? 

Right. But those sources are not easily or readily available. I have not come across a credible academic website which does not specifically and explicitly cite its sources. To me, those are arbitrary. Unless, you can find these sources used in academic research, papers, or books, I fail to believe their accuracy. Have you seen the primary documents?

Comment: Maybe we should just apply this logic to your post? .. and there was I thinking we were discussing the lack of any reference in your post rather than your academic disdain for the secondary source in my post!

Comment: Wow. Complaining about England not being the UK is about as important as people complaining if someone calls the USA, America. ie: Not at all.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the minefields didn't block the Channel entirely, and the British knew where the mines were. The mines were a trap for German vessels, but the British could still navigate the Channel.

Comment: @Shane No. Pointing out that England is not the UK is like pointing out that Texas isn't the USA. The key difference with "America" is that "America" is a commonly accepted term for the USA that is used by Americans themselves.